# How to import modules implicitly in a haskell stack project?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

This isn't an important issue but I was just wondering if I have some modules in a stack (or cabal doesn't matter in this case) Haskell project, which are imported in a lot of other modules how to make them *public* so that I do not need to keep importing them? I also found out that importing modules is not *transitive* either. I mean this will not be an issue but it will save repetition in a big project. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I think typically this is solved by making a module that *re-exports*. For example for a Yesod server, typically a module named `Import` is made that reexports all important aspects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I also found out that importing modules is not transitive either.

That is indeed correct. But you can *reexport* items. This is what is often done to minimize imports. For example if you create a *Yesod* webserver, typically there is a module named `Import` that re-exports all important aspects.

You can re-export by simply mentioning variables that are in scope in the module in the export list. For example we can make a module `Import` that exports `maybe` and `either` from two modules:

```
module Import (maybe, either) where

import Data.Either (either)
import Data.Maybe (maybe)
```

By then importing the `Import` module, we get `maybe` an `either` in scope, and these originate from two different modules.

Comment: I'd add that you can also export all entities from a module using module exports as described in point 5 in section 5.2 of the standard: https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html#x11-100016x5